# New Gigabyte SSD reporting 100C but gsmartcontrol says 33C

Tags: ssd, lm-sensors

I just installed a brand new GIGABYTE GP-GSTFS31120GNTD 120Gb SSD.

Psensor reports values of 100C for every value, i.e. Value, Min, Max. The drive appears to be cool, and psensor is correctly reporting the values of my other drives from lm-sensors.

Is there something wrong with the sensor information here? How can I recaliberate or verify that the psensor or lm-sensors information is correct?

Update: gsmartcontrol reports 33C for all values

Answer (score 0):

Just because it's brand new doesn't mean it's going to adhere to reporting standards... (if there are any)

You may find two different temperatures in gnome-disks... I can see the SSD_Life_Left in `smartctl -x` reporting 98... but gnome-disks Smart Data reporting has that enumerated parameter as the temperature. Which is the same value in lmsensors.

The software could be reporting it wrong... or the data could be provided wrong by the drive...